# "MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://""when tried to connect with a .env file

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to connect my project with mongoose, it connects successfully when I use the URL directly in mongoose.connect() function. But after I create a .env file and use it instead of the link in mongoose.connect()function, I am getting an error stating that
 `"MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://""`.

Comment: Remove any single or double quotes you have wrapped your mongodb url with.

Answer (score 4):

in .env file you should be `mongodb+srv://mina:@cluster0.rpjk7vr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

`like that without double quotes`mongodb+srv://mina:@cluster0.rpjk7vr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: yes, keeping mongo_uri in .env without single or double quote, resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try writing code in your `.env` file without writing semicolons between each line.

the dotenv tool worked when I wrote this in my `.env` file instead:

```
MONGO_URL = `mongodb+srv://database_name:database_password@cluster0.fbx6x.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
PORT = 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not using any "" or '' or ; in your .evn file then it will not show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps.

1. Create a .env file in the root of your project and add your environment-specific configurations. remember to use .env as the file name of env file

[image]

[image]

sample .env code

```
DB_HOST = 3000

DB_NAME = mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.ofyhf.mongodb.net/retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**Keep in mind to remove < > and just enter username and password. It is not necessary to use '', or, "", or ``.**

1. Install the dotenv package using npm or yarn.

   npm install dotenv
2. In your Express application, require and configure dotenv before using any environment variables. Determine you use Node Express here the sample code

```html
import express  from 'express'
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

dotenv.config();

const connectionString = process.env.DB_URI || "";    
console.log(`coneection ${connectionString}`)

const client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

let conn;
try {
  conn = await client.connect();
  console.log('done')
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}



const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.send('/ route')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("hello server ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in case these previous answers don't resolve the issue, consider instead of mongoose.connect(uri), to connect through mongoose.createConnection(uri):

```
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(uri)

// then
// connect your models to this connection
```